# How do I implement String.format in Java (GUI Programme)

Tags: java, swing

I can't seem to figure out how to implement String.format into my code such that when the user enters a temperature in Fahrenheit, the Celsius output is presented in 1 d.p. Help appreciated!

```
tfFahrenheit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                double tempIn=Double.parseDouble(tfFahrenheit.getText());
                Celsius=(tempIn-32)/1.8;
                String.format("%.1f", Celsius);
                tfCelsius.setText(Celsius+"");
            }
        });
```

Comment: `String.format` returns the formatted string, it does not modify it in place.

Comment: You need to capture the formatted string and set the text with it

Answer (score 1):

It returns a formatted string, does not edit the variable itself you passed in

```java
tfCelsius.setText(String.format("%.1f", Celcius));
```